# SAPUI5 Annotation structure cannot read property 'IndexOf' undefined

Tags: annotations, sapui5

I've created a local annotation file based on an OData service. 
And even without adding any annotations to the new annotation file, when I open Annotation modeler it says

> Annotation structure cannot read property 'IndexOf' undefined

[image]

And I have not defined any annotations from the service level.

And Even I add some annotaions using the Code view they also not display when I run the application

When I check the console it displays following error

```
2018-08-09 12:18:45.755000 TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
    at Object.getAbsolutePath (https://webide-hf01c42be.dispatcher.us3.hana.ondemand.com/plugins/pluginrepository/annotationmodeler/client/v1.33.1_1526463231420/config-preload.js:1:136)
    at Object.<anonymous> (https://webide-hf01c42be.dispatcher.us3.hana.ondemand.com/plugins/pluginrepository/annotationmodeler/client/v1.33.1_1526463231420/config-preload.js:9:17064)
    at r (https://webide-hf01c42be.dispatcher.us3.hana.ondemand.com/resources/~3502d451b8b72165ef3cf2fa0789ca9b3430f76e~/sap/watt/core/Core-preload.js:43:4628)
    at r._settlePromiseFromHandler (https://webide-hf01c42be.dispatcher.us3.hana.ondemand.com/resources/~3502d451b8b72165ef3cf2fa0789ca9b3430f76e~/sap/watt/core/Core-preload.js:42:23011)
    at r._settlePromise (https://webide-hf01c42be.dispatcher.us3.hana.ondemand.com/resources/~3502d451b8b72165ef3cf2fa0789ca9b3430f76e~/sap/watt/core/Core-preload.js:42:23814)
    at r._settlePromise0 (https://webide-hf01c42be.dispatcher.us3.hana.ondemand.com/resources/~3502d451b8b72165ef3cf2fa0789ca9b3430f76e~/sap/watt/core/Core-preload.js:42:24515)
    at r._settlePromises (https://webide-hf01c42be.dispatcher.us3.hana.ondemand.com/resources/~3502d451b8b72165ef3cf2fa0789ca9b3430f76e~/sap/watt/core/Core-preload.js:42:25845)
    at r._drainQueue (https://webide-hf01c42be.dispatcher.us3.hana.ondemand.com/resources/~3502d451b8b72165ef3cf2fa0789ca9b3430f76e~/sap/watt/core/Core-preload.js:41:12469)
    at r._drainQueues (https://webide-hf01c42be.dispatcher.us3.hana.ondemand.com/resources/~3502d451b8b72165ef3cf2fa0789ca9b3430f76e~/sap/watt/core/Core-preload.js:41:12530)
    at drainQueues (https://webide-hf01c42be.dispatcher.us3.hana.ondemand.com/resources/~3502d451b8b72165ef3cf2fa0789ca9b3430f76e~/sap/watt/core/Core-preload.js:41:10559) -
```